# mvn compile org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Transfer failed

Tags: macos, maven, ssl

I'm facing this problem when I try **mvn compile -X**

```
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    ...
    ... 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    ...
    ...  
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
**Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom**
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1242)
    ...
```

I'm not sure if this is a known problem, but I'm just getting this after I've reinstalled the OS High Sierra here. I can pull/push changes from GitHub, but apparently Maven and brew are having similar SSL errors.

Keep in mind that I'm not using any proxy or behind any VPN. Terminal and IntelliJ also have the same problem. So I think it is something with my OS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Kaspersky anti-virus and this was trying to validate every https connection, blocking every SSL connection which is not validated by this.

Once I have disabled the https verification, everything was back to work normally...

So, the solution is to verify if your anti-virus is validating/blocking "invalid" SSL connections, and don't forget to reboot your computer.

Cheers.